# how to post data stored in an input tag using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

An initial ajax event saves a unique numerical ID into the value attribute of the following input tag:

```
 <input class="avatar-id" id="avatar-id" name="id" value="">
```

I would like to use jquery ajax to send this value to a php script named delete_list.php. I think I am incorrectly using the jquery ajax DATA setting here to pull the value out:

```
$("#dformclose").click(function() {
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel this? Your image and any information in this form will be deleted")) {
    var id = id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:"html",
            url: "delete_list.php",
            data: "#avatar-id.attr(value.id)",
            success: function(response) {
              location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }
         else 
      { 
    return false;
 }
});
```

How can I correctly use this script to process the ID on the php end?

Comment: `$("#avatar-id").val()` will give you value

Comment: Its not secure to delete some data over javascript post request

Answer (score 1):

```
var idValue = $('#avatar-id').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"html",
    url: "delete_list.php",
    data: {id: idValue},
    success: function(response) {
      location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: it appears the whole ajax call isnt running. the file delete_list doesn't show up in my consul log using my Browser dev tool

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

**jquery**

`data: $('input#avatar-id').val(),`

**php**

To access in php use `$_POST['id']`